# Preventing users from entering non-digits in input text field with HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an input field of type text. Users should only be allowed to enter digits in the field. If they attempt to enter a non-digit, like a character, it should be ignored and not display in the field ( and not submitted to the server). I thought I could achieve this with the HTML5 pattern attribute:

```
<input class="form-control" data-remote="true" data-url="/contacts" data-method="put" pattern="^[0-9]*$" type="text" value="123456" name="contact[phone]" id="contact_phone">
```

But it doesn't work as expected. I can still enter any character into the field. There is no form submit button here. As soon as they tab out of field, the ajax call is made.

How can I achieve what I want with html5?

Comment: It's unfriendly to prevent entry of characters, much better to just show a warning message that the content is invalid and don't submit the data until it passes your checks. E.g. people might copy and paste data that contains invalid characters, intending to edit them out. Most common for me is BSB number, which is nearly always written "000-999" but inputs only want digits like "000999". Why not let me paste "012-345" then let me remove the dash?

Comment: Are you looking for `type="number"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you can totally do that by adding `type="number"` to your input field, [It'll  work in most browsers](https://caniuse.com/#search=number).

I'd recommend using sort of regex and a bit of JS to evaluate the input and then replace the input with permitted characters.

```
var phone_input = document.getElementById('contact_phone');

function validDigits(n){
  return n.replace(/[^0-9]+/g, '');
}

phone_input.addEventListener('keyup', function(){
  var field = phone_input.value;
  phone_input.value = validDigits(field);
});
```

[Here's a quick codepen](https://codepen.io/tinusw/pen/QvoEzJ)

I'd also put a bit of validation on the model, just in case someone bypasses the JS.

Comment: oops, just learnt you can do that by adding `type="number"` to your input. But here's an alternative for you I guess!

Comment: `type=number` allows some specific to numbers characters like `+, -, ., e`. If your goal is to input only digits it doesn't work well

Answer (score 0):

I think it won't work with plain html5 since the pattern goes into affect after you submitted the form (It will make validation fail). But since you are already using js, you can just do it with for example the `jQuery.keypress()` function.